# How to animate lines using SVG.js

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, svg.js

I am trying to animate a line that I have drawn using the SVG.js library. I've tried adding the animate() method but for some reason, it's not working.

I have tried to hide() the line I have drawn first then show and animate it after. What am I doing wrong here?

The lines should be hidden on load - then animate into their positions after.

Please run the code to take a look.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var draw = SVG('frame-1').size(300, 268);
  var line = draw.line(0, 0, 0, 268).stroke({
    width: 1,
    color: '#000'
  });
  var line2 = draw.line(0, 60, 300, 60).stroke({
    width: 1,
    color: '#000'
  });

  var draw2 = SVG('frame-2').size(300, 268);

  var line3 = draw2.line(300, 0, 300, 268).stroke({
    width: 1,
    color: '#000'
  });

  var line4 = draw2.line(0, 208, 300, 208).stroke({
    width: 1,
    color: '#000'
  });

  line3.hide();
  line3.show().animate({
    ease: '<',
    delay: '1.5s'
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.6.5/svg.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="frame-1"></div>
<div id="frame-2"></div>
```

Comment: using `animate()` and then _nothing_ after that will do exactly that: nothing. When you want to animate a line you need to `line.animate().plot(newPoints)` as stated in the docs: http://svgjs.com/elements/#line-plot

Comment: @Fuzzyma so - if I set the opacity of the line to 0 and position it at the bottom of my div, then plot the new points to where it should slide in to with line.animate().plot() - will this work? Or am i not thinking of it right

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to have fade in effect, animate the opacity. If you want to move the line, animate with move. If you want to animate to another line, use plot

Comment: @Fuzzyma Just trying to slide the lines in #frame-1 from the top of the page and lines in #frame-2 from the bottom of the page. They should be hidden initially.

Comment: in that case `animate().plot(new line position).opacity(1)` will do the job i guess

Answer (score 0):

The functions *hide()* & *show()* breaks the animate effect.
I think you are trying something like this:

`line3.attr('opacity',0).animate(1500,'<').attr('opacity',1);`